# What's the meaning of "Run away now, there's a good girl"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

It's a sample sentence in Google Dictionary:

> run along
>
> phrasal verb of run
>
> 1.*informal*
>
> go away (used typically to address a child).
>
> "**run along now, there's a good girl**"
>
> *synonyms*:    go away, be off (with you), shoo; More

(https://www.google.com/search?q=run+along&oq=run+along&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l4.2010j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Do it mean "If you go away now, you are (still) a good girl"?

Or "You'd better hit the road now, especially when/because there's a good girl (somewhere else) waiting for you"?

Comment: Please see [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/is-google-dictionary-a-valid-definition-reference-in-particular-in-answers/11484#11484).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Run away*" and "*run along*" may seem similar but are used quite differently. The difference is idiomatic. Your question title says one but the body of your question asks about the other, so I will address both.

*Run away* is self explanatory. It means to depart (at speed) *from* something, because "away" is a relative direction meaning anywhere but here.

*Run along* is an idiom which is an order to leave, not in any particular direction, but "along" implies that the person *continue* with their other business.

Your example:

> "run along now, there's a good girl"

I would describe this as *quaint British English* and would expect to see it in period literature, either said to a little girl by an elder as a way of asking her to perhaps go and play elsewhere; or perhaps said to someone older as way of patronising them. The implication is that they are behaving, or being a "good girl" by following the order to go away.

In this instance "there" is not used as a direction, but as a sort of *introduction*, the way you might say "there's somebody at the door".

Answer (score 4):

In essence it means,

> I am asking you to leave and, as you are a good girl, I expect you to do so.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation of the meaning.  It might be noted that this language "condescending"  It is how some people talk to children. It would be rather rude to speak to an adult this way.

Answer (score 3):

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**there's a good boy/girl/dog!**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-s-a-good-boy-girl-dog)

> used to show approval or encouragement

It matches your first idea:

> If you go away now, you are a good girl

Comment: +1. Compare **thatta girl!** and **thatta boy!** (**attagirl!** and **attaboy!** ). It can be encouraging or condescending, depending upon the relationship of the parties.